# Must I call (admob) loadAd in onCreate?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, crash, admob

I'm trying to use admob in an android app.  Very simple code, taken right from the examples.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
...stuff...

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "{my id}");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("{my ad unit id}");

    AdRequest aRequest;
    aRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(aRequest);
}
```

...and it works fine.

HOWEVER: I don't want this code here.  I want it to be somewhere else where I explicitely say "Initialize Ads."

When I do that, loadAd crashes, every single time.  The only place I can successfully call it is in OnCreate, or in a callback defined in OnCreate.  Is this a real thing, or is it some threading issue?  Is the game crashing because loadAd is blocking the UI thread or something like that?

I'm not so great at Java (I'm a c++ guy)... if that's the problem, how can I throw the whole shebang into another thread?

Comment: What is the error in the crash log ?

Comment: Use MobileAds.initialize in oncreate and later you can loadAd anywhere anytime. It would be good if you can paste the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved my own problem.  Putting this here for posterity in case anyone else ever needs this solution.

loadAd and showAd MUST happen in the UI thread.  If you invoke them in another thread, that's the crash.

So, it's a very simple thing to wrap those calls like so:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            AdRequest aRequest;
            aRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(aRequest);
        }
    });
```

...and add whatever helper infrastructure you might need if you need that call to act synchronous.

Comment: Unfortunately, this blocks the UI thread, but it seems like there is no way around this.

Comment: @Mark, did you solved the 'blocks the UI thread' problem by mInterstitialAd.loadAd?